# Design pattern: how to pass parent object ID to form for HttpPost processing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

I have to following class hierarchy:

```
public class Parent
{
    public int ID {get;set;}
    public string SomeOtherProperty {get;set;}
    ...
    public virtual ICollection<Child> Children {get;set;}
}

public class Child
{
    public int ID {get;set;}
    public string SomeChildProperty {get;set;}
    ...
    public virtual Parent Parent {get;set;}
}

pubic class ViewModel
{
   public ICollection<Parent> Parents {get; set;}
   public NewChildVM ChildToAdd {get;set}

}

public class NewChildVM
{
   public int ParentID {get; set;}
   public string SomeChildProperty {get; set;} 
}
```

Essentially the ViewModel is a collection of Parent objects, each of which has a collection of child objects.  I also want to pass in a proxy child object which will be used to populate a form in the view.  The view loops through the Parent objects, with some header details, then displays the form for input, then displays a list of the child objects for the parent.

```
foreach(Parent Prnt in Parents)
{
  @Html.BeginForm()
  {
    <fieldset>
        <legend>new message:</legend>
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.ChildToAdd.SomeChildProperty)
        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.ChildToAdd.SomeChildProperty)
        @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.ChildToAdd.ParentID, new { Value = Prnt.ID.ToString() })
    </fieldset>
    <input type="submit" value="SEND"/>

  }
  foreach(Child  Chld in Prnt.Children)
  {
      ... do the html for the child listing
  }
}
```

I am struggling to get the ParentID to populate in the form.  Using @Html.HiddenFor I can't populate the attribute 'value' ( can populate 'Value') but that doesn't get read back automatically when I pass the NewChildVM into the HttpPost version of the method.

I think there are two ways to approach this, The first is the way that I am (trying) to do it where there is one copy of the NewChildVM as part of the VM - in which case how do I populate the 'value' in the form in the actual view. The other way would be to create a ParentVM that inherits from Parent and move the NewChildVM to be a property in the ParentVM which means that one is associated with instance of the Parent which does not feel right to me; but if this is the way to approach it, how do I populate the NewChildVM.ParentID with the ParentVM.ID in the ViewModel?

Answer (score 0):

Having posted a slightly different question which did get a response, in the end I replaced the HiddenFor with a hand-crafted

```
<input type="hidden" value="Prnt.ID.ToString()" name="ChildToAdd.ParentID"/>
```

and in the [HttpPost] decorated ActionResult set the binding to be the ChildToAdd element of the vm

```
public ActionResult Conversations([Bind(Prefix="ChildToAdd")] Child vm )
```

I hope this helps someone else.